# Parse xml with python with xml.etree

Tags: python, xml

I've got xml such as:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
 <EventID>4771</EventID> 
 <Version>0</Version> 
 <Level>0</Level> 
 <Task>14339</Task> 
 <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
 <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords> 
 <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-08-07T18:10:21.495462300Z" /> 
 <EventRecordID>166708</EventRecordID> 
 <Correlation /> 
 <Execution ProcessID="520" ThreadID="1084" /> 
 <Channel>Security</Channel> 
 <Computer>DC01.contoso.local</Computer> 
 <Security /> 
 </System>
 <EventData>
 <Data Name="TargetUserName">dadmin</Data> 
 <Data Name="TargetSid">S-1-5-21-3457937927-2839227994-823803824-1104</Data> 
 <Data Name="ServiceName">krbtgt/CONTOSO.LOCAL</Data> 
 <Data Name="TicketOptions">0x40810010</Data> 
 <Data Name="Status">0x10</Data> 
 <Data Name="PreAuthType">15</Data> 
 <Data Name="IpAddress">::ffff:10.0.0.12</Data> 
 <Data Name="IpPort">49254</Data> 
 <Data Name="CertIssuerName" /> 
 <Data Name="CertSerialNumber" /> 
 <Data Name="CertThumbprint" /> 
 </EventData>
 </Event>
```

And i want to read data from this xml, using list of input() tags, as EventID, Computer, TargetUserName, IpAddress, etc.

I've got some code, which can parse System, but how to parse EventData cildnodes and childnodes values?:

```
from tkinter.font import names
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('C:/tmp/test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

namespace = "{"+root.tag.split('}')[0].strip('{')+"}"

for child in root:
  print(child.tag, child.attrib)
  print((''.join([child.tag for child in child.iter()])).replace(namespace,"| "))

print("\n\n\n\n")
testlist = ["EventID", "Computer"]
i = 0
for tag in testlist:
  for tag in root.iter(namespace+tag): #'EventID'
    print(testlist[i],":",tag.text)
    i += 1
```

The result I need to get:

```
System: Provider Name | EventID | Version | Level | Task | Opcode | Keywords | TimeCreated | EventRecordID | ProcessID | ThreadID | Channel | Computer
EventData: TargetUserName | TargetSid | ServiceName | TicketOptions | Status | PreAuthType | IpAddress | IpPort | CertIssuerName | CertSerialNumber | CertThumbprint
    
EventID : 4771
Status : 0x10
PreAuthType : 15
Computer : DC01.contoso.local
TimeCreated : 2015-08-07T18:10:21.495462300Z
TargetUserName : dadmin
ServiceName : krbtgt/CONTOSO.LOCAL
IpAddress : ::ffff:10.0.0.12
IpPort : 49254
```

Comment: Yes, children of EventData

Comment: And how to get all names of childnodes in EventData (TargetUserName .. CertThumbprint)?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your expected output from the sample xml?

Comment: Added information about the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current colution:

```
from tkinter.font import names
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime

tree = ET.parse('C:/tmp/test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

namespace = "{"+root.tag.split('}')[0].strip('{')+"}"

for system in root.iter(namespace+'System'):
  print('System: ', ''.join({x.tag for x in root.findall(system.tag+"/*")}).replace(namespace,", "))

data = ""
for eventdata in root.iter(namespace+'Data'):
    data = data + str(eventdata.attrib).replace("{'Name': '","").replace("'}",", ")
print('EventData: ',data)

print("\nEnter all tags to search separated by commas or leave blank to use default list: EventID, TimeCreated, Computer, TargetUserName, IpAddress, IpPort")
list = input().split(',')
if list == ['']:
  list = "EventID", "TimeCreated", "Computer","TargetUserName", "IpAddress", "IpPort" 

i = 0
for searchtag in list:
  for tag in root.iter(namespace+searchtag):
    if searchtag == "TimeCreated":
      time = str(tag.attrib).replace("{'SystemTime': '","").replace("'}","")
      print(list[i], datetime.strptime(time.split(".", 3)[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
      
    else:
      print(list[i],":", tag.text)
    i += 1

for searchtag in list:      
  for tag in root.iter(namespace+'Data'):
    if (str(tag.attrib).replace("{'Name': '","").replace("'}","") == searchtag):
      print(str(tag.attrib).replace("{'Name': '","").replace("'}",""),":", tag.text)

print("\n\n")
```